# Where does Plex media server store its cache/settings?

Tags: plex

I just want to know where to find the cache/settings locations for Plex Media Server? I just want to save it in case I need to reformat my drive.

I'm not sure if it matters but I am using Ubuntu 14.xx. And I installed Plex by downloading the .deb package that's available on its site. The one of the repo is too old.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Ubuntu/Debian settings and library stored in `/var/lib/plexmediaserver/...`.

The PlexMediaScanner (cli-commands) can be found under `/usr/lib/plexmediaserver/`

Comment: The path is same for Debian, too.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the location for the various Linux versions of Plex Media Server will be found under:

$PLEX_HOME/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/

Just cd to this path and all settings should be there. Usually this path should be under your home directory. In Ubuntu you can check where the path is by running:

```
cat /etc/default/plexmediaserver | grep  PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR
```

Comment: On my machine, that _cat grep_ command reveals that the _export_ line is commented out, and I wonder why! Instead, I found the files in `"/var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server"`.